# How to ligate DNA to an RNA molecule

Tags: ligation

Is it possible to ligate a small DNA molecule to mRNA?  I was reading a protocol from Current Protocols in Molecular Biology and one of the procedures involve ligating a DNA molecule to mRNA using a DNA splint that overlaps between the 5' of the DNA molecule and the 3' of the mRNA.

Would a reaction like the following work?

5'-phosphorylated DNA linker
mRNA library
DNA splint
T4 DNA ligase + buffer

Comment: T4 ssRNA ligase will work for this.. Check [this](https://www.neb.com/products/m0204-t4-rna-ligase-1-ssrna-ligase) page on NEB site.